# In ONC RPC, is it valid to call svc_run() from two threads, registered with different program no?

Tags: c++, c, rpc

In our project which supports multiplatform (Linux, Solaris, and Windows) and coded in C and C++, we are using **ONC RPC** for IPC.
Recently there is a requirement to have an application server to work on two different programs no.

I have tried the following to test.

*Created a multithread application
    Within that created two worker threads*

```
    In first thread I’m
         a) Creating a TCP transport
         b) Registering the transport
         c) Calling svc_run

    In second thread I’
         a) Creating a second TCP transport
         b) Registering the transport with a different program no
         c) Calling svc_run*
```

I have tried this on [Red Hat Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux) 4, and it's working fine for me.

But is it valid to register two programs no and call svc_run in two different threads?

I have tried searching the Internet, but I was not able to find any clear information on this.

Answer (score 2):

It seems logical that this is possible, although I never tried it myself.

Please not the `-M` command switch of `rpcgen` IDL compiler (this is from its `man` page on Solaris):

```
 -M          Generates multithread-safe stubs for passing
             arguments   and   results   between  rpcgen-
             generated code and user written  code.  This
             option  is useful  for users who want to use
             threads in their code.
```

If the proxy/stub code is thread-safe, and you register two event loops with 2 different RPC process numbers--my guess is this should behave as if you actually had 2 different processes (RPC-wise).

Comment: I realize I'm late to the party but: What you are describing is only for solaris. rpcgen in linux does not support this (and does not have the `rpc_control` function available in solaris).